# How do I use TCHAR* Provided in Cmd Line Argument in Switch Statement?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, switch-statement

Here's what I've got:

```
 switch(argv[0])
 {
  case "-test1":
   AfxBeginThread(method1, 0); break;
  case "-test2":
   AfxBeginThread(method2, 0); break;
  case "-test3":
   AfxBeginThread(method3, 0); break;
  default:
   AfxBeginThread(method1, 0); break;
 }
```

I'm using windows so the arguments come into the array as TCHAR*'s. What do I need to do to make this work?

Edit:

So I'm trying to do the following now...

```
if(strcmp(argv[0], "-http") == 0)
    doStuff();
```

I'm getting the following compile error

error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *'
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast.

Help?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What doesn't work right now? Compile error? Runtime error? Logic error?

Comment: @Alex Zylman: "integral expression required"

Comment: @SigTerm: You should listen to the error messages your compiler gives you. As James said in his answer, switch cases in C/C++ only accept integer types. That's also the same error that your compiler is giving you.

Comment: @Alex Zylman: First, it isn't MY question. Second, if you already know what'll happen, why asking?

Comment: No need to get so offended about a naming issue - I wasn't paying attention to names, I just assumed the person answering me would be the creator of the question. And I didn't know what would happen when I first posted my comment. If you'll notice, I posted before James posted his answer. Without knowing that switch only works with integer types in C++ (which I had forgotten about until James said it), you would need more information that "it's broken" to fix something.

Comment: @Alex: In comments, the nick of the one who asked the question is always highlighted, so you can't miss it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't switch over values that are not constant integral values. But since argument matching isn't time critical, you can put in a couple of `if`'s and `strcmp`'s instead.

This code runs apparently under Windows, you're most likely forced to use `TCHAR`, which means that you need `_tcscmp()` instead of `strcmp`, and the good old `_T()` macro:

```
 if      (_tcscmp(_T("-test1"),argv[0])==0) AfxBeginThread(method1, 0);
 else if (_tcscmp(_T("-test2"),argv[0])==0) AfxBeginThread(method2, 0);
 else if (_tcscmp(_T("-test3"),argv[0])==0) AfxBeginThread(method3, 0);
 else AfxBeginThread(method1, 0);
```

The `TCHAR, _tcscmp` and `_T()` thing is explained here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321(v=VS.80).aspx

Short story is, that you can build your program for various character representations (16-bit UCS-2, 8 bit multibyte etc.) from a single source by using these macros, which expand to the right function (`_tcscmp->strcmp or wcscmp or mbccmp`) depending of the character representation you are building for.

Comment: This worked, but I had to make it argv[1] instead of argv[0]. I guess the first is reserved. Thanks!

Also, I noticed that my app is using wchar's rather than just normal chars. I'm running XP. Shouldn't it be using ASCII by default not UNICODE?

Answer (score 4):

That won't work.   In C/C++, `switch` only works with integer types.

In other languages (VB, C#), you can use any data type in a switch statement, but in C & C++, you can only use integer types (`int`, `long`, `char` etc).

The reason for this is that when using ints, there is an optimization available over using chained `if()`.  `switch` was created to take advantage of that optimization.  Later on, people realized, it made the code neater, and added it to other languages --- but just as a shorthand for chained if()s -- without taking advantage of the optimization.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I need to do to make this work?

Something like this:

```
// Beware, un-compiled code ahead!
namespace {
  typedef std::map<std::basic_string<TCHAR>,AFX_THREADPROC> thread_func_map_type;
  typedef thread_func_map_type::value_type thread_func_entry_type;

  const thread_func_entry_type thread_func_entries[] =
  { thread_func_entry_type(_T("-test1"), method1)
  , thread_func_entry_type(_T("-test2"), method2)
  , thread_func_entry_type(_T("-test3"), method3) };

  const thread_func_map_type thread_func_map( thread_func_entries
                                            , thread_func_entries 
                                            + thread_func_entries
                                            / thread_func_entries[0] );
}

// ...

thread_func_map_type::const_iterator it = thread_func_map.find(argv[1]);
if( it == thread_func_map.end() )
  it = thread_func_map.find("-test1");
assert(it!=thread_func_map.end());
AfxBeginThread(it->second, 0);
```

Comment: heh - I was just coding up a C variant of this (too much embedded work...)

Comment: This doesn't address the TCHAR issue.